# ASP.NET retrieve Average CPU Usage

Tags: asp.net, performance, performancecounter

Last night I did a load test on a site. I found that one of my shared caches is a bottleneck. I'm using a ReaderWriterLockSlim to control the updates of the data. Unfortunately at one point there are ~200 requests trying to update the data at approximately the same time. This also coincided with CPU usage spikes.

The data being updated is in the ASP.NET Cache. What I'd like to do is if the CPU usage is around 75%, I'd like to just skip the cache and hit the database on another machine.

My problem is that I don't know how expensive it is to create a new performance counter to check the cpu usage. Also, if I would probably like the average cpu usage over the last 2 or 3 seconds. However, I can't sit there and calculate the cpu time as that would take longer than it's taking to update the cache currently.

Is there an easy way to get the average CPU usage? Are there any drawbacks to this?

I'm also considering totaling the wait count for the lock and then at a certain threshold switch over to the database. The concern I had with this approach would be that changing hardware might allow more locks with less of a strain on the system. And also finding the right balance for the threshold would be cumbersome and it doesn't take into account any other load on the machine. But it's a simple approach, and simple is 99% of the time better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This article from Microsoft covers [Tuning .Net Application Performance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647813%28v=pandp.10%29.aspx) and highlights which counters to collect and compare to determine CPU and I/O bound applications.

You sound like you want to monitor this during execution and bypass your cache when things get intensive. Would this not just move the intensive processing from the cache calls to your database calls? Surely you have the cache to avoid expensive DB calls.

Are you trying to repopulate an invalidated cache? What is the affect of serving stale data from the cache? You could just lock on the re-populating function and serve stale data to other requests until the process completes.

Based on the above article, we collect the following counter objects during our tests and that gives us all the necessary counters to determine the bottlenecks.

- .NET CLR Exceptions
- .NET CLR Memory
- ASP.NET Applications
- ASP.NET
- Memory
- Paging File
- Processor
- Thread

The sections in the article for [CLR Tuning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647813(v=pandp.10).aspx#scalenetchapt17_topic13) and [ASP.NET Tuning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647813(v=pandp.10).aspx#scalenetchapt17_topic14) highlight the bottlenecks that can occur and suggest configuration changes to improve performance. We certainly made changes to the thread pool settings to get better performance.

[Changing and Retrieving Performance Counter Values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s155t6ta%28VS.71%29.aspx) might help with accessing the existing Processor counter via code but this isn't something I've tried personally.

Comment: After reviewing the concept of stale data and what actual parts of the data are stale, it makes sense to "You could just lock on the re-populating function and serve stale data to other requests until the process completes." .. Thanks!